# Exception in Entity Framework SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make an insert in a SQL database using Entity Framework 6 and I'm stuck on this issue that I cannot solve.

The error that I keep getting is :

> UpdateException: Entities in 'Connect.CompanyFinancialDetails' participate in the 'Company_CompanyFinancialDetails' relationship. 0 related 'Company_CompanyFinancialDetails_Source' were found. 1 'Company_CompanyFinancialDetails_Source' is expected

I have these 2 entities:

```
public class Company
{
    public long CUI { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public int? SharesCount { get; set; }
    public decimal? SharePrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyFinancialDetails CompanyFinancialDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyFinancialDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    public decimal? NumberOfEmployees { get; set; }      
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Fluent API configuration:

```
    public DbSet<Account> SignUpModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CompanyFinancialDetails> CompanyFinancialDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
           .HasKey(k => k.Id)
           .HasOptional(s => s.Company)
           .WithRequired(d => d.Account);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
           .HasKey(k => k.CUI)
           .HasOptional(s => s.CompanyFinancialDetails)
           .WithRequired(d => d.Company);
    }
```

The relationship that I want to have is 1-many (one `Company` has many `CompanyFinancialDetails`).

This is the code where I add the objects to the database:

```
Company co = Context.Find(username);

foreach (CompanyFinancialDetails s in c)
{                       
    s.Company = co;
}

a.CompanyFinancialDetails.AddRange(c);
a.SaveChanges();
```

I get a list of `CompanyFinancialDetails` and I add them using the `AddRange` method. I had this issue before and what I did was to add the virtual property object to the object that I wanted to insert in the database and it worked. This is what I tried to do here: the `Find()` method gets the company object that is related to the `CompanyFinancialDetails` and for each `CompanyFinancialDetails`  object an `Company` virtual property is adding the related company object.

Well, it didn't work, when the `SaveChanges()` method is called, I get that error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `one Company gas many CompanyFinancialDetails` doesn't correspond to `public virtual CompanyFinancialDetails CompanyFinancialDetails { get; set; }`.

Comment: You mean that I should add IEnumerable<CompanyFinancialDetails> on that property instead of  CompanyFinancialDetails ? Do you think this would solve the problem ?

Comment: Whether it solves everything I don't know, but defining a Company as having a single FincancialDetails is definitely not the right way to model a 1-n relationship.

Comment: It should be `ICollection<CompanyFinancialDetails>`. Also, I'd use a singular name for the class (`CompanyFinancialDetail`) and plural for the collection.